# Integrar Jquery en JSP

Tags: jquery

soy nueva utilizando la funcion de JQuery, tengo un formulario html en un archivo JSP e integre Jquery, pero no funciona, estoy utilizando eclipse Neon y estoy desarrollando un portlet en Liferay. 
Si alguien me pudiera orientar, se los agradezco.

```
$(document).on('ready',function(){
    var username ="test@liferay.com";
    var password ="1234";
    function make_base_auth(user, password) {
    var tok = user + ':' + password;
    var hash = btoa(tok);
    return "Basic " + hash;

  }
     $.ajax({
     url: 'http://192.168.15.31:8080/api/jsonws/portletliferay.creditos/get-credito/solicitud-id/84610',
     dataType: "json",
     type: "post",
     success: function(data){
     alert(data.estadocred);

  },

  beforeSend: function(xhr){
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization',make_base_auth(username, password));

  },

   complete: function(){

  },

    error: function(){

   }
});
```

});

```
<form id="formulario" method="post">

<div>
    <label for="nombre">Nombre(s)</label><input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre">
</div>

<div>
  <label for="apellido">Apellidos</label><input type="text" name="apellido" id="apellido">
</div>

<div>
  <label for="fechaNac">Fecha de Nacimiento</label><input type="text" name="fechaNac" id="fechaNac">
</div>

<div>
  <label for="genero">Genero</label><input type="text" name="genero" id="genero">
</div>

<div>
  <label for="RFC">RFC</label><input type="text" name="RFC" id="RFC">
</div>

 <div>
  <label for="creScore">creScore</label><input type="text" name="creScore" id="creScore">
</div>

 <div>
  <label for="creDisponible">Credito Disponible</label><input type="text" name="creDisponible" id="creDisponible">
</div>

 <div>
  <label for="salarioMensual">Salario Mensual</label><input type="text" name="salarioMensual" id="salarioMensual">
</div>

<div>
  <label for="telcasa">Telefono de Casa</label><input type="text" name="telcasa" id="telcasa">
</div>

<div>
  <label for="telpart">Telefono Particular</label><input type="text" name="telpart" id="telpart">
</div>

<div>
  <label for="email">Email</label><input type="text" name="email" id="email">
</div>

 <div>
  <label for="calleynumero">Calle y Número</label><input type="text" name="calleynumero" id="calleynumero">
</div>

<div>
  <label for="colonia">Colonia</label><input type="text" name="colonia" id="colonia">
</div>

 <div>
  <label for="colonia">Delegación o Municipio</label><input type="text" name="delmun" id="delmun">
</div>

<div>
  <label for="estado">Estado</label><input type="text" name="estado" id="estado">
</div>

 <div>
  <label for="cp">CP</label><input type="text" name="cp" id="cp">
</div>

<div>
  <button class="button" type="submit" id="enviar">Enviar</button>
</div>
```

Tengo que enviar datos a traves de este formulario.

Comment: Deberías añadir algo más de información: el formulario ¿No se envía, o se envía con datos incorrectos, o se envía pero no llega...? ¿Cómo no funciona? Si abres la consola de JS, ¿aparece algún mensaje de error?

Comment: Tal vez no me supe explicar, el objetivo de lo que estoy desarrollando es un portlet en la plataforma Liferay DXP. En Eclipse Neon, cree un nuevo proyecto, del cual en el archivo view.jsp realice mi formulario en formato HTML, y añadi un script implementando JQuery Ajax. Dicho resultado debe ser que en mi portlet donde se aloja mi formulario debo ingresar datos y esos datos se deben de ver en una base de datos que esta alojada en otra PC.

Comment: Mi error es que no puedo hacer que esos datos ingresados y enviados por mi formulario no pueden ser visualizados en la otra pc :(